# How to start a jQuery effect when a user visualizes a point of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw a lot of sites with this feature. Eg: I scroll the page until the footer, and when I see the footer an image inside it starts animating. In short, that image will start the animation only when I'll visualize the footer. How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Something like `$(window).scroll(function(){ if ("window bottom == footer bottom") { /*start some animation*/ } });`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($('#footer').offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        console.log('footer is inside viewport');
    }
});
```

Basicly you are checking the distance to the top of the document. The height of the window has to be added, otherwise it would only trigger if the `#footer` element is at top of the window which would be too late.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway i tried the code but the animation starts as soon as i scroll, it doesn't wait that i arrive at the page footer.

Comment: Please check my answer again. The calculation was wrong. You have to check the scroll amount + the window height to get the window bottom to document top distance. Compare this to the elements absolute position to the document top and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$(window).height()` gives the height of the viewport.
2. `$(window).scrollTop()` is how far down the window has been scrolled.
3. `$('#footer').offset().top` is how far the top of the footer element is from the top of the document.

By subtracting 2 from 3, you get how far it is from the top of the viewport to the top of the footer element. If that is less than 1 (the height of the viewport), the footer is in view.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (($('#footer').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < $(window).height()) {
        // Start animation
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the right solution for me. Just a curiosity: do you think there's some way of using window pageYOffset property for the same purpose?

Comment: @FabyKennedy - I think for modern browsers, `window.pageYOffset` will give the same value as `$(window).scrollTop()`, but if you are using jQuery, you should just use `$(window).scrollTop()`.